# Put email addresses stored in an array into "To" field of an Outlook email

Tags: vba, outlook

I want email addresses that are stored in the array "emails" put into the "To" part of an email.

I get a type mismatch error.

```vb
Sub Email_Click()
    Dim myOutlook As Outlook.Application
    Dim objMailMessage As Outlook.MailItem

    Dim emails As Variant
    emails = Array("a@a.com", "b@b.com")
  
    Set myOutlook = Outlook.Application
    Set objMailMessage = myOutlook.CreateItem(0)
    
    With objMailMessage
        .Display
        .To = emails
        .Subject = ""
        .HTMLBody = ""
        
        .Save
        .Close olPromptForSave
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: `.To = Join(emails, ";")` I'm assuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close this question out, use `Join`:

```
.To = Join(emails, ";")
```